# Change POST params in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, post

It is needed to send several requests to the same url with different POST parameters. For setting POST parameter, the following code is used (and it works):

> private void setPostParams(HttpURLConnection connection, String 
>      paramsStr) {
>
> ```
>     byte[] outputInBytes=null;
>     try {
>         outputInBytes = paramsStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
>     }
>     catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {};
>     OutputStream os;
>     try {
>         os = connection.getOutputStream();
>         os.write( outputInBytes );
>         os.close();
>     }
>     catch (IOException e) {}
> }
> ```

However, before setting the next parameter, it is needed to delete the previous one, and I don't know whether it is possible. Of course, it is possible to save the 'base' connection, and each time add the parameter to new copy of connection. However, this way seems to be ugly especially because it is impossible to use simple `HttpURLConnection connectionBase=connection` which creates two pointers to the same connection.

I try to inspect `HttpURLConnection` in debug session to find where the string of POST params are saved, but found nothing.
Maybe, it is possible to edit previously added POST parameters from `HttpURLConnection` object, or the only way is to use 'base connection'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is even more complicate: I cannot find a legal way to clone `HttpURLConnection`. So, the only solution that I see now is to create a new copy of `HttpURLConnection` each time for the next parameter. So, it would be required as many copy of `HttpURLConnection' as there are many parameters need to be passed to request.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. 'Before setting the next parameter, it is necessary to delete the previous one' is meaningless. This code writes one set of parameters to the connection. Next time you use it, there will be a new connection, at least logically, and no parameters yet written. You don't need to clone anything: `HttpURLConnection` does TCP connection pooling under the hood.

Comment: EJP, please tell me what is the logic for creating new connections in my case, when url (and other settings) remains the same one, only the POST parameter is altered.

Comment: Same as how you created the first one. `URLConnection.openConnection()`. Please tell us what your *actual* problem is. Everything you've mentioned so far as a problem is imaginary.

Comment: It is needed to insert several  (maybe 50-100) records to mysql db via request to php script. I woudn't like to create one request with a long parameter string, because it can be too long. I'd like to send several (50-100) requests to the same script changing POST parameter.

Comment: And what makes you think you aren't doing exactly that?

Comment: Do you plan on answering that question? It is critical in determining whether there is any problem here to be solved, or rather what exactly that problem is, other than your own misconceptions.

Comment: EJP, thanks for help. I've heard your key phrase that 'HttpURLConnection' isn't reusable, and it was my question: why I cannot use the same `HttpURLConnection' if url is the same, only POST params alter. My logic (and, I think, a logic of any programmer) for such a case is try to use the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

> However, before setting the next parameter, it is needed to delete the previous one

No it isn't.

> and I don't [know] whether it is possible.

It is neither possible nor necessary.

> Of course, it is possible to save the 'base' connection

No it isn't. There is no 'base connection' to save, and they aren't reusable.

> and each time add the parameter to new copy of connection.

You aren't adding parameters to the connection. You are writing them to an output stream, which sends them to the network.

> However, this way seems to be ugly especially because it is impossible to use simple HttpURLConnection connectionBase=connection which creates two pointers to the same connection.

You don't need two pointers to the same connection. You can't reuse them. `HttpURLConnection` does TCP connection pooling behind the scenes, if that's what you're worrying about.

> I try to inspect HttpURLConnection in debug session to find where the string of POST params are saved

They aren't saved in the `HttpURLConnection`. They are sent to the server, after the HTTP headers.

> but found nothing.

There is nothing to find.

> Maybe, it is possible to edit previously added POST parameters from HttpURLConnection object

They aren't there to be edited.

> or the only way is to use 'base connection'?

There is no such thing.

You're barking up the wrong tree entirely here. You need to state your *actual* problem, if any. Everything you've mentioned so far as a problem is imaginary.

Comment: Dear EJP, yours critic about how to formulate the question is quite correct, but you don't answer my question. My actual task is the following: to insert several (maybe 50-100) records to mysql db via request to php script, and to avoid very long param str.

Comment: Rubbish. I've answered everything you asked, and a lot more besides. Specifically, there is no problem here to solve. And I repeat. What makes you think you aren't doing exactly that already? There is nothing in the code you posted that will cause parameters to be sent twice. All you need is a new connection each time, which I have also already told you how to get, and to call the code you posted.

Comment: EJP, you didn't understand my question, maybe because of bad formulating. The code I've posted is about to add one parameter string, and it works. However, the task is to generate about 50-100 requests with the same url and different parameters. If calling my function `setPostParams` each time with the same connection, new parameters will be written, and the previous ones remain. So, the question was if it is possible to delete previously added parameter (parameters).

Comment: You didn't understand either my answer or my comment. For at least the third time: you cannot reuse an `HttpURLConnection` *in any way*, and the previous parameters *therefore* do *not* remain. You have to use a new `HttpURLConnection` each time. You have no choice about this, and that fact alone makes your entire question moot.